# Molecular dynamics: Lennard-Jones forces in 2D system

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fortran, molecular-dynamics

As I am new to all these stuff I would like to verify whether my procedure is correct.

I need to calculate the Lennard-Jones potential, potential energy of the system and the forces.

The procedure is as follows:

1) Read the input data: side lenght of the square -a, number of particles -N, the parameters $\sigma$, $\epsilon$

2) For $i=1,n$ insert randomly n points in x and y axis.

- 2a) For $j=i+1,n+1$ calculate the difference to square between
  particles in x and y axis.
- 2b) If $r_{ij} \leq 2^{1/6}\sigma$ go back to 2a) step
- 2c) End of the both loops

3) For $i=1,n$

- 3a) For $j=i+1,+1$ calculate the lennard jones potential $$u_{ij}=4\epsilon[(\sigma/r_{ij})^{12}-(\sigma/r_{ij})^6]$$ where $r_{ij}$ is being calculated in 2a) step
- 3b) calculate the potential energy of the system
  $$U_N=\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=i+1}^N u_{ij}(r_{ij})$$
- 3c) Calculate the force $$F=\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^NF_{ij}$$ where $$F_{ij}=(-\nabla_ju_{ij}(r_{ij}))$$
- 3d) End of the both loops

I would really grateful for checking, whether it is even correct.
I would also appreciate any books connected to this problem - I am currently using Allend Tildesley, but it is rather difficult for me at start.

Comment: Why do you need step 2b?  As far as I can tell, it determines whether two particles i and j are too close to each other, this will lead to high values of the pairwise potential $u_{ij}$ that you cannot neglect.

Comment: Because the particles cannot overlap.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot just ignore overlapping particles.  You have to compute their corresponding forces (which will be large in magnitude because of the overlap).

Comment: Ah right, I was meant to tell that if the distance is less that $2^{1/6}\sigma$ then we should "loss" the position of that particular particle again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "loss" but you don't have to do anything special with those particles.  Another thing that is not correct is the loop for $j$ = $i+1$ to $N+1$  (it should be $N$, not $N+1$).  Regarding 3b and 3c, keep in mind that you have to compute $u_{ij}$ and $-\nabla u_{ij}$ and *accumulate* those results into $U_N$ and $F$.  The rest of what you wrote looks OK.  Good luck!

Comment: Oh, and don't forget that that $F_{ij} = -F_{ji}$.

Comment: Ah right, I meant to generate not "loss". Thank You for those hints. They are really helpful!

Comment: I misread 2b and thought it was during the simulation instead of being the set up, you are free to regenerate those points of course.  Now I think you have everything in place.

Comment: I would be also very grateful for some source, where I can check whether my results are correct - I mean, how the plots should look like.